# Why does AutoMapper not format my date properly?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, automapper

I have the following mappings configured in my MVC Core 2.0 application:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>(MemberList.None)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BirthDate, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.BirthDate.ToString(AppConstants.DefaultDateFormat)));

cfg.CreateMap<PersonViewModel, Person>(MemberList.None)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BirthDate,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => DateTime.ParseExact(src.BirthDate, AppConstants.DefaultDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

where `AppConstants.DefaultDateFormat` is `yyyy-MM-dd`. The destination date string in the `PersonViewModel` displays as `1969-12-13T00:00:00`
.

`src.BirthDate` is of type `DateTime`, not nullable, and `dest.BirthDate` is of type `string`. I specifically made it a `string` so that I could define a custom mapping to format the date.

Why does AutoMapper seem to ignore my custom mapping and just do a default `ToString()` on the source date? Am I somehow doing the custom mapping incorrectly?

Comment: A better question is why are you converting the date to a string in the first place... ;)

Comment: @DavidG As I clearly said in the question, so that I can format it for display, e.g. I would normally do `BirthDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say "clearly", but, that's still a bad idea. Your models shouldn't define formatting, keep that in the UI layer.

Comment: @DavidG It is formatted in the viewmodel - I would say that's pretty much in the UI layer, wouldn't you? The viewmodel is used in several places, so I seriously don't want to go format the date in my Razor markup everywhere it occurs.

Comment: Can you show the code that uses AutoMapper to convert from `Person` to `PersonViewModel`?

Comment: Dont use `ResolveUsing`, use `MapFrom` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration works when used with `Map` method, but is failing when used  with `ProjectTo`.

When `ProjectTo` is applied on EF Core 2 query, AutoMapper up to version 6.2.0 produces the aforementioned behavior, while new newer versions (6.2.0, 6.2.1 and 6.2.2 at the time of writing) produce runtime exception when executing the resulting query.

Regardless of the AutoMapper versions behavior differences, the main problem is that you should not use `ResolveUsing` for such scenario, as denoted at the end of the method description:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Resolve destination member using a custom value resolver callback. Used instead
//     of MapFrom when not simply redirecting a source member This method cannot be
//     used in conjunction with LINQ query projection
//
```

The above also contains the solution, especially for your scenario. Simply replacing `ResolveUsing` with `MapFrom` works correctly in all the cases and all aforementioned AutoMapper versions:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>(MemberList.None)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BirthDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BirthDate.ToString(AppConstants.DefaultDateFormat)));
```

Comment: I have exact same issue and even if I am using MapFrom, it is not converting date to desired format but to default format of my system. I am using Automapper v 10.0. In short the mapping which I am adding does not not have any effect. My code is like CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
    .ForMember(d => d.ExpiryDateUtc, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.ExpiryDateUtc.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))); Any input?

Comment: Never mind, I got the cause. It was because my mapping was getting overridden by other CreateMap call for IncludeMember method.

Answer (score 2):

What you return from resolvers gets mapped to the final destination value (DateTime.ToString() in this case). That won't happen with a type converter or a value transformer.

Comment: Which am I using? A type converter, or a value transformer?

Comment: I would try a type converter and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

While the initial issue is focused on the problem of the mapper, I would like to change the focus onto improving the design choice.

Borrowing a concept from DDD (Domain Driven Design) consider using a value object to represent the `BirthDate` value of the view model.

I created a base object to cover the repeated functionality

```
public abstract class ValueObject<T> where T : ValueObject<T> {

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        var valueObject = obj as T;

        if (ReferenceEquals(valueObject, null))
            return false;

        return EqualsCore(valueObject);
    }

    private bool EqualsCore(T other) {
        return GetEqualityComponents().SequenceEqual(other.GetEqualityComponents());
    }

    protected abstract IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents();

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return GetEqualityComponents()
            .Aggregate(1, (current, obj) => current * 23 + (obj == null ? 0 : obj.GetHashCode()));
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null) && ReferenceEquals(right, null))
            return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null) || ReferenceEquals(right, null))
            return false;

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right) {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}
```

and then following the desired pattern create a `BirthDate` value object

```
public class BirthDate : ValueObject<BirthDate>, IEquatable<BirthDate> {
    DateTime value;

    public BirthDate(DateTime value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator BirthDate(DateTime dt) {
        return new BirthDate(dt);
    }

    public static implicit operator BirthDate(string src) {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(src, AppConstants.DefaultDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public static implicit operator DateTime(BirthDate dt) {
        return dt.value;
    }

    public static implicit operator String(BirthDate dt) {
        return dt.ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return value.ToString(AppConstants.DefaultDateFormat);
    }

    public bool Equals(BirthDate other) {
        return DateTime.Equals(this.value, other.value);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents() {
        yield return value;
    }

}
```

Note the implicit operators that allow for the conversion of the value object between the desired types. Mainly `DateTime` and formatted `string`

The view model would have the value object as a property

```
public class PersonViewModel {
    //...

    public BirthDate BirthDate { get; set; } <-- note the return type

    //...
}
```

The following unit tests were used to exercise the conversion between the different value object and desired types even via the mapper.

```
[TestClass]
public class BirthDateValueObjectTests {

    public class Person {
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonViewModel {
        public BirthDate BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

    string date = "1981-05-14";

    static BirthDateValueObjectTests() {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(_ => {

        });
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void BirthDate_Should_Implcit_Convert_From_DateTimeProperty() {
        //Arrange
        var birthDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
        var person = new Person {
            BirthDate = birthDate
        };
        var expected = new BirthDate(birthDate);

        var mapper = AutoMapper.Mapper.Instance;

        //Act
        var actual = mapper.Map<PersonViewModel>(person);

        //Assert
        actual.BirthDate
            .Should().NotBeNull()
            .And.Be(expected);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void BirthDate_Should_Implcit_Convert_To_DateTimeProperty() {
        //Arrange
        var birthDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
        var person = new PersonViewModel {
            BirthDate = new BirthDate(birthDate)
        };
        var expected = birthDate;

        var mapper = AutoMapper.Mapper.Instance;

        //Act
        var actual = mapper.Map<Person>(person);

        //Assert
        actual.BirthDate
            .Should().Be(expected);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void BirthDate_Should_Implicitly_ConvertTo_DateTime() {
        var expected = DateTime.Parse(date);
        var birthDate = new BirthDate(expected);

        DateTime actual = birthDate;

        actual.Should().Be(expected);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void BirthDate_Should_Implicitly_ConvertFrom_DateTime() {
        var birthDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
        var expected = new BirthDate(birthDate);

        BirthDate actual = birthDate;

        actual.Should().Be(expected);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void BirthDate_Should_Implicitly_ConvertTo_String() {
        var expected = DateTime.Parse(date);
        var birthDate = new BirthDate(expected);

        string actual = birthDate;

        actual.Should().Be(date);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void BirthDate_Should_Implicitly_ConvertFrom_String() {
        var birthDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
        var expected = new BirthDate(birthDate);

        BirthDate actual = date;

        actual.Should().Be(expected);
    }

}
```

So now the mapper can convert via direct mapping and the view model's `BirthDate` property can be used in the view with the desired formatting because the implementation concerns that were being done in the mapper configuration is encapsulated in the value object who has the single responsibility of being a birth date.

While this answer targeted the birth date specifically the value object can be renamed and used more generally for other date time properties to reduce repeated code (DRY).

Comment: Good in theory, but in practice works only with `Map` (which OP code does as well) and fails miserably with `ProjectTo`.

Comment: Very nice and informative answer, and I'd love to try it some time, but way too complex for the project I would need it in, a quick and simple proof of concept. I also have an issue with calling that date value object `Birthdate` as I'd want to use it for all dates, and call it something ungainly but descriptive like `DateValueObject`.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked with both Automapper 4.1.1 and 6.2.2 and it works just as you intend it to work. Your mapping transformation is absolutely correct, maybe you have some other error. AppConstants.DefaultDateFormat is empty? or configuration is not executed etc